# How to test ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rspec, ruby-on-rails-6

I'd like to test specific logs that I am generating as part of my code. While it seemed fairly straightforward to test `Rails.logger`, I am wrapping it in `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging`, which I am having trouble testing with...

Here are two methods that I have:

```rb
  def logger
    @logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Rails.logger)
  end

  def log(message)
    logger.tagged('MangaDex::Importer', "User ##{@current_user_id}") do
      logger.info message
    end
  end
```

And then I call it in my code like this:

```rb
    if md_parsed_list.blank?
      log 'List is inaccessible'
      return
    end
```

Now, in my Rspec tests, I've been trying to do something like this:

```rb
  it 'logs and stops execution if there is nothing to import' do
    expect(Spiders::Mangadex).to receive(:parse!)
      .with(:parse, url: import_url)
      .and_return({})

    expect(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging).to receive(Rails.logger)
    expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with('List is inaccessible')
    expect(CreateMangaEntries).not_to receive(:call)

    described_class.perform_async(import_url, user.id)
    described_class.drain
  end
```

I know I am missing some step in connecting TaggedLogging and Rails.logger, as calling the test above just throws an error `undefined method 'to_sym' for #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00007f8fc545db50>`.

Would love some help with this, thanks in advance!

Edit:

After improving the mocking involved based on @Grzegorz, the test ended up looking like this:

```rb
  let(:tagged_logger_double) { instance_double(ActiveSupport::Logger) }

  it 'logs and stops execution if MDList is inaccessible' do
    expect(Spiders::Mangadex).to receive(:parse!)
      .with(:parse, url: import_url)
      .and_return(nil)
    expect(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging)
      .to receive(:new)
      .with(Rails.logger)
      .and_return(tagged_logger_double)
    expect(CreateMangaEntries).not_to receive(:call)
    expect(tagged_logger_double).to receive(:info).with('List is inaccessible')

    described_class.perform_async(import_url, user.id)
    described_class.drain
  end
```

I had to slightly change the double, due to the instance of `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging` being `ActiveSupport::Logger`.

I was able to resolve the original exception, but still unable to test `receive(:info)` as `tagged` seems to be missing: 
`#<InstanceDouble(ActiveSupport::Logger) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :tagged with ("MangaDex::Importer", "User #2626")`

But when I try to stub that method as well: `allow(tagged_logger_double).to receive(:tagged)`, I get the error that such method doesn't exist: `the ActiveSupport::Logger class does not implement the instance method: tagged`, hene I am still stuck with a failing test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grzegorz correctly answered the first part of your question, so to pick up where he left off...

You’re right that you need to stub `tagged`. The reason you’re getting the method not implemented error is because `ActiveSupport::Logger` does not implement `tagged`. It is extended when wrapped by `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging`.

See the constructor method definition here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TaggedLogging.html#method-c-new

I’m not sure how to use a verifying double in this case. One option is to not do that, and just use a `double`.

Another problem is that you’re not stubbing `tagged` correctly. You need to stub it so that it yields to the block.

Finally, you need to memoise the return value of your `logger` method because you're only expecting `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging` to receive `new` once.

Bringing all this together, I wrote the following test:

```rb
require "rails_helper"
require "custom_logger"

RSpec.describe "CustomLogger" do
  let(:tagged_logger_double) { double("Tagged logger") }

  it "logs" do
    expect(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging)
      .to receive(:new)
      .with(Rails.logger)
      .and_return(tagged_logger_double)

    allow(tagged_logger_double)
      .to receive(:tagged)
      .and_yield

    expect(tagged_logger_double).to receive(:info).with("message")

    CustomLogger.new.log("message")
  end
end
```

This passes with the following code, which I think closely resembles that in your example:

```rb
class CustomLogger
  def log(message)
    logger.tagged("Tag") do
      logger.info message
    end
  end

  def logger
    @_logger ||= ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Rails.logger)
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks! And you were right, I had a bug everywhere, forgetting to memoise logger! Silly me, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

You've passed an object to `.to receive` method, where it's expecting a method name (string or symbol). This is the source of your error, this below would make a bit more sense to me:

```
expect(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging)
  .to receive(:new)
  .with(Rails.logger)
  .and_return(tagged_logger_double)
```

Then you'll have full access to the logger in your specs if you defined it like this

```
let(:tagged_logger_double) { instance_double(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging) }
```

and set your expectations

```
expect(tagged_logger_double).to receive(:info).with('List is inaccessible')
```

Comment: That's a good point, that is the correct way to define the expectation. But its not the whole fix for this. I am now failing at `tagged` as logger from `logger.tagger` now is `nil`. I presume I need to pass in there a double, instead of a logger and then just stub methods on it, but I need to inject it into the code somehow, which I am not entirely sure how

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you'll be able to continue after being unblocked from the immediate error. I updated my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz, mocking is not my strong suit. Your expanded answer definetly helped, but I am stuck again. 

First of all, interestingly, the instance of tagged `Logger` becomes `ActiveSupport::Logger`, so I had to update `tagged_logger_double`. But now I am unable to get to `receive(:info)` because I am missing `tagged`: `#<InstanceDouble(ActiveSupport::Logger) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :tagged with ("MangaDex::Importer", "User #2626")`

Comment: But when I try to stub that method as well: `allow(tagged_logger_double).to receive(:tagged)`, I get the error that such method doesn't exist: `the ActiveSupport::Logger class does not implement the instance method: tagged`, which is all very weird...

Comment: @MaximFedotov Sorry, but comments are not the best place to expand on the original question. Please post another question if you're stuck somewhere else. Also, if my answer was helpful please consider up-voting and accepting to help others with similar problem.

Comment: I left an upvote @Grzegorz, but I still see this as an unresolved question. I wanted to get to a passing test, and would rather not to separate this into another question, to retain the context.

I've updated the description to include the updated code and the new issue I am having now

Comment: Sorry mate, but it's unresolved because you made a mistake: `let(:tagged_logger_double) { instance_double(ActiveSupport::Logger) }` But I wrote `let(:tagged_logger_double) { instance_double(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging) }`

Comment: Please double check my description. I used `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging` first, but it didn't work and by doing a pry session, I realised calling `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Rails.logger)` returns `ActiveSupport::Logger`. So I had to change it. If I don't, I get `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging class does not implement the instance method: info`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to test tags and message which has been logged.
This code worked for me.

```
let(:logger) { ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Rails.logger) }

before do
    allow(logger).to receive(:tagged).and_call_original
    allow(logger).to receive(:info).and_call_original
    allow(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging).to receive(:new).and_return(logger)
end

it 'logs with correct tags' do
  expect(logger).to have_received(:tagged).with(tags)
end

it 'logs with correct message' do
  expect(logger).to have_received(:info).with(message)
end
```